# How to sort a stream by parameter using a comparator in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, higher-order-functions, java-stream

How to sort a collection using comparator and a parameter in Java 8?

Here is a piece of code:

```
    List<Point> sortedNeurons = neurons.parallelStream()
        .sorted((n1, n2) -> Double.compare(
            n1.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(inputVector),
            n2.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(inputVector)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You are given a parameter inputVector that can be passed to a function that returns a primitive double value. If applied to an element of the collection, it returns some number.
I want the collection to be ordered by this value.
Something like: select id from neurons order by getEuclideanDistanceFrom(inputVector, id);

There are three problems here:

1. nx.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(inputVector) gets repeated twice.
2. I would like to use natural ordering of a double type, without declaring it, just like in an SQL query, when using order by clause.
3. Perhaps n1, n2 -> n1, n2 could be substituted with a double colon :: notation.

P.S. I have a strong feeling that it can be fixed using something like bifunction or biconsumer... but couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can do it with [`Comparator#comparingDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-):

```
List<Point> sortedNeurons = neurons.parallelStream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(inputVector)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks good. I made it even better:

```
List<Point> sortedNeurons = neurons.parallelStream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(inputVector::getEuclideanDistanceFrom))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then I realized, you can make it even shorter:

```
List<Point> sortedNeurons =
neurons.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(inputVector::getEuclideanDistanceFrom));
```

Apparently streams are not good for sorting things...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "streams are not good for sorting things." The first snippet seems quite reasonable. If `neurons` is a list, the second snippet doesn't work. The `List.sort()` method sorts the list in place and returns void.

Comment: you are right. This makes all I need. From 5 lines of code I got to 1! It just cannot be better `neurons.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(inputVector::getEuclideanDistanceFrom));`

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way to extract the comparator that can be reused:

```
public interface Functional<T> {
    public int compareByEuclideanDistance(T o1, T o2);
}

public class Point implements Functional<Point> {
    @Override
    public int compareByEuclideanDistance(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return Double.compare(this.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(o1),
            this.getEuclideanDistanceFrom(o2));
    }
}
```

Now you can make any call such as:

```
neurons.parallelStream()
    .sorted(input::compareByEuclideanDistance)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
neurons.parallelStream().min(input::compareByEuclideanDistance).get();
```